# How to syntax highlight multiple-space-separated fields in vim?

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I have a trace format that has space-separated fields, but with an unknown number of spaces between them, e.g.:

```
  0.0430   22.0  83012/84348 mt-client * | |        clearing session cache
  0.0430    0.0  83012/84348 mt-client * | |        moving 1 sessions into watched list
  0.0430    0.0  83012/84348 mt-client * | |        session 8 added to watched list
  0.0430    0.0  83012/84348 conncache - | --27.0 ConnectionCache::ResetEverything
```

I'd like to syntax highlight in vim based on the field number - e.g., what awk would call $1, $2, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following pattern will match the first non-whitespace group, what awk calls $1:

```
:syn match Keyword /\v(^\s*(\S+\s+){0})@<=\S+/
```

You can change `{0}` into `{1}` to match second group, and `{i-1}` for the `$i` group.

Before highlighting, you may customize your own highlight group.

For example:

```
:highlight Group0 guifg=blue
:highlight Group1 ctermfg=black ctermbg=white
```

First one is for gui mode, and second one for cli mode. Or you can set both at the same time.

---

#### save highlight rules to a file

You can save your customized rules into a file, so that you can easily highlight such strings in the future.

Save following content to `my_highlight.vim`

```
"customize highlight groups
highlight Group0 guifg=blue
highlight Group1 guifg=green
highlight Group2 guifg=yellow
highlight Group3 guifg=orange
highlight Group4 guifg=purple

"highlight groups
syn match Group0 /\v(^\s*(\S+\s+){0})@<=\S+/
syn match Group1 /\v(^\s*(\S+\s+){1})@<=\S+/
syn match Group2 /\v(^\s*(\S+\s+){2})@<=\S+/
syn match Group3 /\v(^\s*(\S+\s+){3})@<=\S+/
syn match Group4 /\v(^\s*(\S+\s+){4})@<=\S+/
```

Just execute following command when you need to highlight:

```
:source my_highlight.vim
```

Comment: I was thinking about making the pattern more dynamic but had no idea. Your one is definitely better but I think the `[^ ]` is more appropriate since `\S` character class contains both spaces and tabs. Nevertheless, thanks for `\v`, sometimes it is hard to backslash everything.

Comment: Well, you are right. By using `[^ ]` we can strictly match the space. But in this case, we tend to consider both space and tab as delimiter, right?

Comment: Depending on trace format, of course. Nothing about tabs as a delimiter in question but I suppose trace can have tabs.

Comment: Note to anyone else who doesn't read carefully and gets stuck for 10 minutes: for cli-mode, you need ctermfg, not guifg!

Comment: @dmd Thank you for pointing that out, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

To get an idea place this text into the buffer and type `/^\s*\zs[^ ]\+`. This pattern selects the first field. To select the second one use this: `^\s*[^ ]\+ \+\zs[^ ]\+`. To select the third one use this: `^\s*[^ ]\+ \+[^ ]\+ \+\zs[^ ]\+` and so on. `\zs` does not highlight preceding atoms. To make a syntax on this use:

```
syntax match {group} /{pattern}/
```

For instance:

```
syntax match Keyword /^\s*\zs[^ ]\+/
```